# autocomplete='off' does not work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have an input field `<input type='text' name='user' autocomplete='off'>` but autocomplete is still active.

This is what I see when I inspect the element

[image]

It seems that Firefox somehow thinks that this field is a password field and uses the build-in [Login Manager storage module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Creating_a_login_manager_storage_module). I did not use any Javascript on this input element.

I also noticed a strange `key` symbol at the autocomplete drop-down list

[image]

How can I get rid of that key symbol and disable autocomplete?

Heres my HTML Code

```
<form class='clearfix'>
  <div id='loginForm'>
    <label>
      Login 
      <span>
      <a href='/memberArea/lostPass.php' id='hackB'>
       Forgot Password? Click here!</a></span>
    </label>
    <input type='text' name='user' id='username' autocomplete="off">
    <label  >Password </label>
    <input type='password' name='pass' id='passLogin' autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <button class='confirmbutton' id='loginButton'>Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sry, not a direct answer, but is that the same as autocomplete? -- http://caniuse.com/#search=autofill ...seems you're saying autofill but your code says autocomplete. probably the same.

Comment: your question is about `autofill` but in your code you are using `autocomplete`?

Comment: yeah sorry I ment `autocomplete` I will just edit it

Comment: try Adding  autocomplete="off" to the form also

Comment: In some cases, the browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This unexpected behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to really forcing the no-autocompletion is to assign a random string to the attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#section_4

Comment: Just for ref, caniuse.com has this note: "many modern browsers ignore the off value on certain fields in certain cases intentionally in order to give the user more control over autofilling fields. One example is the use of password managers."

Comment: By the way, I hate it when websites attempt to disable that. I enabled my password manager so I don't have to retype that information

Comment: @JuanMendes yes I agree. The question came up because someone recommended to disable autocomplete to fix another issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586903/jquery-keep-hovering-despite-browser-proposal-from-input-element). However, I have now found a solution without the need to disable autocomplete. I guess one should not mess with autocomplete :)

Answer (score 1):

Clear browser, Try,

```
<!--
  <form autocomplete="off"> will turn off autocomplete for the form in most browsers
  except for username/email/password fields
  -->
<form autocomplete="off">

  <!--  fake fields are a workaround for chrome/opera autofill getting the wrong fields -->
  <input id="username" style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered">
  <input id="password" style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered">

  <!--
    <input autocomplete="nope"> turns off autocomplete on many other browsers that don't respect
    the form's "off", but not for "password" inputs.
  -->
  <input id="real-username" type="text" autocomplete="nope">

  <!--
    <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" will turn it off for passwords everywhere
    -->
  <input id="real-password" type="password" autocomplete="new-password">

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! What you mean with clear browser? Close and reopen browser, or clear cache?

Comment: I cleared the `Cached Web Content` and used your code. However, autocomplete is still active on that element, but now without the key symbol anymore.